# Nodejs Express for web aplication JWT with database or sessions to authenticate users

Tags: node.js, express, session, jwt

I'm developing a NodeJs with Express server and I have many problems with the JWT authentication that is suposed to be the new standard.

The main problem is when I have an admin users manager section in my app. I don't know a "good" way to delete or avoid client tokens access.

I read about doing a blacklist DB with tokens with a short expiration time defined, but the idea is to allow users to be logged for months and don't have to rewrite the login data (something like facebook). In this mode I think that the blacklist DB will be a huge database.

Another option could be to keep all tokens in a DB and verify all requests against that DB deleting tokens when an user is deleted.

or simply validate all requests against users DB testing if the users exists. This method uses lots of DB interactions.

I could have a problem about the same user whith tokens in different devices.

On the other side, in the frontend I will have to navigate via ajax or adding the token dynamically to all href links. (Probably a better way?)

Must I use any of thes methods? Are there a better solution? Could be better the use of sessions?

Comment: What about `sessions`? Its so flexible and I guess it definitely what you need

Comment: Probably, but I read that sessions could have problems with mobile phones. I didn't have to use sessions in the past because I usually work on Frontend, so do you know if there is any kind of problems integrating webs with session on mobile phones? Probably I will need to integrate webs inside phone apps without browsers too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For avoiding the use of aditional DB or blacklist, whitelist or some kind of logout/remove users control. The problem could be resolved using jwt with low expired time (I'm using 15 min) having the user un playload (obviously not the password).

In each request, I verify the sign of the token and if the user is still active in DB the token is valid (this resolves deleted users problem). then it generates a new token with its 15 new min of expired time and the client replaces the token (the older one only still working a maximun of 15 min)

When logout, the client removes the token (the expired time could be a maximun of 15 min so I think that couldn't be a security problem preserving the stateless finallity of the JWTs)

When a user is removed from DB his tokens are automatically disabled (and in a max of 15 min will expire) (Its important to expire because could be the case of a user with the same name registering in the future)

By deffault users have to login when access to the app, but with a "keep me signed" buttom we could solve the problem of low expiration time of the tokem by securely store the data on client (I have to study if this part is applicable).

This solves too the mobile phone problem inside webviews.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your own JWT, you can store that type of information in the token itself. `role: 'User'` or `isAdmin = true`. Then when using the token on the client app, if they are not admins, do not show those pages.

**Make sure your API calls on the server verify the token, and also check for privileges**. Even if someone used their client-access token from the web to an admin endpoint (page accidentally showed or super hax0rs), the server should deny.

This type of approach works if the access types do not change often, like "admin or not admin". Likely you will not upgrade users to be admins all the time. If you tried this same thing for more specific access that changes often, it's a mess because you need to keep re-issuing tokens or redacting tokens (which is harder).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the problem is not about role to access to expecific private areas. The idea is when admin deletes an user from database, which of those methods could work better (or another methods that I don't know or if is preferable the use of sessions in this case) I have the aditional problem in "the use of sessions" way, about integrating the web inside a mobile webview without a browser (I don't know if it allow sessins and cookies.

Comment: I see. Revoking JWT tokens is similar to revoking session keys - something has to check the "truth". Either 1) track the tokens themselves as a "white list", if you can find the referenced token in the list, it's still valid. Delete from list if needed to revoke, which I guess implies token identifier each time it is issued. Or 2) check the user data on each access. The token ensures what is sent is not changed and verified, the user access is business logic and would have to be verified as well. No extra token storage though, the token has the user identifier and that is checked normally.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that storing tokens in database to verify in each requests needs a database aditional storage and lots of requests to db (more server capacity and probably more slow) and loses the jwt logic (stateless) and for testing the user data on each access is necesary to keep those credentials stored on client which is an insecure option.